# SQL Join Query help

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing some SQL exercise and having this problem, this query below gives me a 'half correct' result because I only want the row(s) with the most title to be displayed, this query is displaying all records. Can someone help? Thanks.

**Question:**

Which were the busiest years for 'John Travolta'. Show the number of movies he made for each year.

**Tables:**

- `movie (id, title, yr, score, votes, director)`
- `actor (id, name)`
- `casting (movieid, actorid, ord)`

**Query:**

```
select yr, max(title)
from 
(
select yr, count(title) title from movie
join casting
on (movie.id=casting.movieid)
join actor
on (casting.actorid=actor.id)
where actor.name="John Travolta"
group by yr Asc
) a
```

Comment: and so what do you get? And which half of that is correct, which is incorrect??

Comment: Also, the problem you outline doesn't go with the question.  The question states to "Show the number of movies he made for each year."  It says nothing about limiting it to only 1 year.

Comment: http://sqlzoo.net/3.htm
See 4a. That's what I have there. Or maybe I should say row(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks

> Which were the busiest *years*?

... plural. So, what were his top 5 years?

```
select top 5
 m.yr
,count(*)
from actor as a
    join casting as c
        join movie as m
        on m.movieid = c.movieid
    on c.actorid = a.actorid
where a.name = 'John Travolta'
group by
 m.yr
order by
 count(*) desc
```

**However**, the second part of the question specifies that you should

> Show the number of movies he made for *each year*.

So far our query doesn't account for years in which John made no movies... so, this might be where your *half correct* comes into play. That said, you may want to create a table variable filled with year values from 1954 through the current year... and left join off of that.

```
declare @year table
(
    [yr] int
)
declare @currentYear int = datepart(year,getdate())
while @currentYear >= 1954 begin -- Travolta was born in 1954!

    insert @year values (@currentYear)
    set @currentYear -= 1

end

select
 y.yr
,count(m.movieid)
from @year y
    left join movies as m
        join casting as c
            join actor as a
            on a.actorid = c.actorid
            and a.name = 'John Travolta'
        on c.movieid = m.movieid
    on m.yr = y.yr
group by
 y.yr
order by
,count(m.movieid) desc
```

**[Edit: based on comments]** And a final query to return all years whose count matches the highest of any year.

```
;with TravoltaMovies as
(
    select
     m.yr
    ,count(*) as [Count]
    from actor as a
        join casting as c
            join movie as m
            on m.movieid = c.movieid
        on c.actorid = a.actorid
    where a.name = 'John Travolta'
    group by m.yr
)
select
*
from TravoltaMovies as tm
where tm.[Count] = (select max([Count]) from TravoltaMovies)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, maybe the site sqlzoo.com is not very clear with its question, "Which were the busiest years for 'John Travolta'. Show the number of movies he made for each year." is one question. Its actually wants the row(s) which consist of 2 column: the year and number of movie title of his busiest years. Based on the site, the answer should return 2 rows because he made 2 movies in each of those years.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is:

```
SELECT y.yr,MAX(y.count)
FROM(
SELECT movie.yr,COUNT(movie.yr) AS count
FROM (movie JOIN casting ON (movie.id=movieid)) JOIN actor ON (actor.id=actorid)
WHERE name='John Travolta'
GROUP BY yr
ORDER BY COUNT(movie.yr) DESC) y
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much easy solution.

```
select yr, count(yr)  
from movie 
join casting on movie.id = movieid
join actor on actorid = actor.id
where name = 'John Travolta' 
group by yr
having count(yr) > 2**
```

Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

```
select TOP 1 yr, title
from 
(
select yr, count(title) title from movie
join casting
on (movie.id=casting.movieid)
join actor
on (casting.actorid=actor.id)
where actor.name="John Travolta"
group by yr Asc
) a
ORDER BY title DESC
```

Just add a `TOP` selection and an `ORDER BY`.

The aggregation is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all this is the query:

```
SELECT yr,COUNT(title) FROM
  movie JOIN casting ON movie.id=movieid
         JOIN actor   ON actorid=actor.id
where name='John Travolta'
GROUP BY yr
HAVING COUNT(title)=(SELECT MAX(c) FROM
(SELECT yr,COUNT(title) AS c FROM
   movie JOIN casting ON movie.id=movieid
         JOIN actor   ON actorid=actor.id
 where name='John Travolta'
 GROUP BY yr) AS t
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This a simple answer using both join and sub-query concept

`select yr,count(title) from movie
inner join casting on
movie.id=casting.movieid
where actorid= (select id from actor where name ='John Travolta') 
group by yr 
having count(title)>2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier solution with explanation-

1. First we make a join of all the tables
2. Then we put a category filter on name with name= 'John Travolta'
3. Now we put a group function on yr so that we have yr and corresponding count(yr)
4. Solution wants to have years with count>2 only so we apply that filter on grouped data by using 'having' clause

   `select yr, count(yr) from movie
   join casting on movie.id=movieid
   join actor on actor.id=actorid
   where name= 'John Travolta' 
   group by yr 
   having count(yr)>2`

Hope this helps, I dont see a need to write a Procedure for this.